# Resolution proof involving more than a literal

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show that the following clauses are unsatisfiable together using resolution (i.e. obtain a refutation):

1: $\lnot P_1 \lor \lnot P_2$

2: $P_2 \lor \lnot P_3$

3. $P_1 \land P_3$

I perform resolution with 1 and 2 to get:

4. $\lnot P_1 \lor \lnot P_3$ 
   which is equivalent to 4'. $\lnot(P_1\land P_3)$ by DeMorgan's law. Can I now resolve 4' with 1 to conclude the proof? Or must I resolve only on $P_i$ for some $i$? If that is the case, can I conclude the proof?

Answer (score 1):

3. is not a disjunctive [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)).

In [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) the sentence to be proved must be in conjunctive normal form with the conjuncts represented as elements in a set of clauses.

Thus, instead of 3., you must have 3': $P_1$ and 3'': $P_3$. Now, you can conclude with 4: $\lnot P_1 \lor \lnot P_3$.